# Solving $2^{2\sin x}+2^{\sin x}-6=0$

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone help me with this question. The mark scheme says its C but i have no idea why or how you get to that.

[image: Trigonometry question]

Comment: Have you tried putting the various suggested solutions (or example elements of sets) into the original equation? Also note that $2^{\sin x}$ will always be positive and the maximum value occurs when $\sin x=1$ so that the first two terms are both constrained in value, and you can solve this without doing anything complicated at all - it is about seeing something quite simple and not being distracted by apparent complexity.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let $t=2^{\sin x}$ then

$$2^{2\sin x}+2^{\sin x}-6=0 \iff t^2+t-6=(t+3)(t-2)=0$$

Comment: can you tell me how you proceed from here to the answer c I know you can now write 2^sinx=-3 or 2^sinx=2. But what do we do after

Comment: $2^{\sin x}=-3$ has not solution since $2^{\sin x}>0$ and $2^{\sin x}=2 \iff \sin x=1$

Answer (score 1):

As $2^{2\sin x}=(2^{\sin x})^2.$

If $2^{\sin x}=y,$  as $-1\le\sin x\le1\implies2^{-1}\le y\le2^1$

we have $$y^2+y-6=0$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a quadratic in the variable $2^{\sin x}$.  Make the substitution $u = 2^{\sin x}$ to obtain
$$  u^2 + u - 6 = 0  $$
and factor, revealing
$$  (u+3)(u-2) = 0  \text{.}  $$
This says either $2^{\sin x} = -3$ or $2^{\sin x} = 2$.  Since powers of $2$ are never negative, we discard the former and continue studying the latter.  For $2^{\sin x}$ to be $2$, $\sin x = 1$.  (The function $2^v$ is one-to-one, meaning there is only one power of $2$ that is equal to $2$, in particular, the first power.)

Now we just have trigonometry.  From
$$  \sin x = 1 $$
we (generically) have the two infinite families of solutions
$$  x = \arcsin(1) + 2 \pi k  $$
and
$$  x = \pi - \arcsin(1) + 2 \pi k  \text{,}  $$
for any integer $k$.  You should know $\arcsin(1) = \pi/2$, so both of these familes are actually the same family (because $\pi/2 = \pi - \pi/2$).

Comment: oh thank you so much i can finally see it now. I wasnt sure where to go from the 2^sinx=2

Answer (score 0):

How it is stated above it the set such that  $\sin (x)=1 $ although there are also non-real solutions for $2^{\sin x}=-3$. Take a look at Wolfram graphs.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%7B2sin+x%7D%2B2%5Esin%28x%29-6%3D0

Answer (score 0):

As a final step after the other hints:

Once you get the roots for $t=2^{\sin x}$, check which ones correspond to real values of $x$.  You have to have $-1\le\sin x\le+1$ so $(1/2)\le t\le 2$.  For all roots for $t$ that satisfy this result, find $\sin x$ and match that to the choices given to find the correct one.  Remember that the sine is periodic and you have to identify the right period.